# A call to Bind was not well formatted.Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="5">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image Width="100" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("~/sqldread2/{0}") %>' runat="server" />
        <br />
    <ItemStyle BorderColor="Brown" BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="3px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
</asp:DataList>
```

> Error - Data bind is not well formatted.

I want to print following image array.
I think I want to add `sqldread2` to `DataList`, `GridView` or `ListView`

```
while (sqldread2.Read())
{
    Context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])sqldread2["Image"]);
    Context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";

    al.Add(sqldread2);
    sDatAdp.SelectCommand = scmd1;

    dtlist.DataSource = sqldread2;
    dtlist.DataBind();
}
```